# Error while try to go forward or skip the videos in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I don't know if the problem is common or anyone faces this problem because I searched but I didn't find any solution for this problem, my problem is when I try to skip or go forward in any video it's didn't work or return me to the 0 s,

so I tried a different video player to solve this problem but didn't work so the problem seems to come from Django, I tried to use a different database like Postgres from SQLite and it's didn't also work

Comment: What videos are you referring to?

Comment: @MichielB, mp4 videos, I read the reason for this because I working in the virtual environment,  I test all the browsers no one work except the firefox and I would apple to go forward in the videos.

Comment: The problem is you ask a very general question on how 'in any video' you have a problem with Django. And also how you tried different video players to solve the problem. But you never show any code, or any error messages. So it's very difficult for anyone to help you with this. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask